# Pandas: Divide 2 data frames of different sizes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 data frames - `df_TB` and `df_FX`. I'd like to keep all columns from `df_TB` and divide all `df_TB.values` by corresponding `df_FX.values`

I have tried below, which results in `NaN` for everything

```
index_FX = ['Year', 'PL/BS', 'Currency']
df_TB = df_TB.set_index(index_FX)
df_TB = df_TB / df_FX
```

And also tried below, which also results in NaN for everything... Although 'df_TB2' does produce what I expected. But I can't seem to take df_TB / df_TB2. I am not able to multiply them either (thought that would resolve any divide by zero errors)

```
df_TB2 = pd.DataFrame(index=df_TB.index).join(df_FX)
df_TB = df_TB / df_TB2
```

I am very new to Python and Pandas (also new to Stack Overflow). Any help on this is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

> df_TB:

| Year | Entity | PL/BS | MAM Account | PC | Currency | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 6156 | BS | 1002 | X6156901 | AUD | -100 | -100 | -100 | -100 | -100 |
| 2019 | 6154 | BS | 1031 | X6154901 | USD | -642344.73 | -642344.73 | -642344.73 | -642344.73 | -642344.73 |
| 2020 | 6157 | BS | 1031 | X6157002 | GBP | 2849621.42 | 2849621.42 | 2849621.42 | 2849621.42 | 2849621.42 |
| 2019 | 6227 | BS | 1031 | X6227901 | SGD | 659535.71 | 659535.71 | 659535.71 | 659535.71 | 659535.71 |
| 2020 | 6156 | BS | 1031 | X6156999 | AUD | -3604681.34 | -3604681.34 | -3604681.34 | -3604681.34 | -3604681.34 |
| 2019 | 6154 | PL | 2288 | X6154002 | USD | 3588.59 | 3588.59 | 4843.88 | 4843.88 | 4843.88 |
| 2019 | 6227 | PL | 2828 | X6227002 | SGD | -299.05 | -398.73 | -533.29 | -667.84 | -802.39 |
| 2019 | 6157 | PL | 4001 | X6157002 | GBP | 0 | 0 | 500 | 0 | 0 |
| 2020 | 6377 | PL | 4001 | X6377006 | JPY | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1000 |

> df_FX:

| Year | PL/BS | Currency | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | BS | AUD | 1.3938 | 1.3751 | 1.4087 | 1.4113 | 1.4183 |
| 2019 | BS | GBP | 0.7946 | 0.7621 | 0.7538 | 0.7523 | 0.7667 |
| 2019 | BS | JPY | 113.3823 | 108.821 | 111.3249 | 111.4868 | 111.3667 |
| 2019 | BS | SGD | 1.3764 | 1.3461 | 1.3517 | 1.353 | 1.3602 |
| 2019 | BS | USD | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2019 | PL | AUD | 0 | 1.3987 | 1.3997 | 1.4028 | 1.4044 |
| 2019 | PL | GBP | 0 | 0.7759 | 0.7724 | 0.7698 | 0.768 |
| 2019 | PL | JPY | 0 | 109.0216 | 109.6882 | 110.0554 | 110.543 |
| 2019 | PL | SGD | 0 | 1.3566 | 1.3554 | 1.3555 | 1.3553 |
| 2019 | PL | USD | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020 | BS | AUD | 1.4529 | 1.4946 | 1.5342 | 1.6124 | 1.5329 |
| 2020 | BS | GBP | 0.7503 | 0.7572 | 0.7802 | 0.8133 | 0.7948 |
| 2020 | BS | JPY | 109.3067 | 108.3296 | 107.9176 | 107.5538 | 106.9397 |
| 2020 | BS | SGD | 1.3541 | 1.3648 | 1.3933 | 1.4151 | 1.4098 |
| 2020 | BS | USD | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020 | PL | AUD | 0 | 1.4581 | 1.4775 | 1.4886 | 1.5384 |
| 2020 | PL | GBP | 0 | 0.7645 | 0.7679 | 0.7701 | 0.788 |
| 2020 | PL | JPY | 0 | 109.2678 | 109.6086 | 108.8845 | 108.6383 |
| 2020 | PL | SGD | 0 | 1.3513 | 1.3691 | 1.3734 | 1.3946 |
| 2020 | PL | USD | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

**Expected Result**

| Year | Entity | PL/BS | MAM Account | PC | Currency | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 6156 | BS | 1002 | X6156901 | AUD | -68.83 | -66.91 | -65.18 | -62.02 | -65.24 |
| 2019 | 6154 | BS | 1031 | X6154901 | USD | -642344.73 | -642344.73 | -642344.73 | -642344.73 | -642344.73 |
| 2020 | 6157 | BS | 1031 | X6157002 | GBP | 3797976.04 | 3763366.9 | 3652424.28 | 3503776.49 | 3585331.43 |
| 2019 | 6227 | BS | 1031 | X6227901 | SGD | 479174.45 | 489960.41 | 487930.54 | 487461.72 | 484881.42 |
| 2020 | 6156 | BS | 1031 | X6156999 | AUD | -2481025.08 | -2411803.39 | -2349551.13 | -2235599.94 | -2351543.7 |
| 2019 | 6154 | PL | 2288 | X6154002 | USD | NaN | 3588.59 | 4843.88 | 4843.88 | 4843.88 |
| 2019 | 6227 | PL | 2828 | X6227002 | SGD | NaN | -293.92 | -393.46 | -492.69 | -592.04 |
| 2019 | 6157 | PL | 4001 | X6157002 | GBP | NaN | 0 | 647.33 | 0 | 0 |
| 2020 | 6377 | PL | 4001 | X6377006 | JPY | NaN | 0 | 0 | 0 | 9.2 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly make both `df_FX` and `df_TB` equal by length so for this we are making change in `df_FX` and this can be done by `reindex()` method:-

```
df_FX=df_FX.reindex(df_TB.index)
```

Finally we are using `round()` method so that we can round the divisions of columns upto 2 decimal places:-

```
df_TB[['0','1','2','3','4']]=round(df_TB[['0','1','2','3','4']]/df_FX[['0','1','2','3','4']],2)
```

Now you you print `df_TB` then you will get your expected output